# PrimeFaces: How to set the p:subtable column's width

Tags: java, javascript, css, primefaces, xhtml

I have the following structure to render in my page:

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.persons}" var="person">
    <p:subTable value="#{person.children}" var="child">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Person: #{person.name}" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column headerText="Name"/>
                <p:column headerText="Years" />
                <p:column headerText="Birth Date" />                
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{child.name}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{child.years}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{child.birthDate}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:subTable
</p:dataTable
```

I want it to be printed like this:

[image]

But unfortutanely, even if I change the "width", "style" or "styleClass" attributes in the "p:column" tags, the widths are always, distributed through the row width in the subtable:

[image]

How can I fix that? Can I fix that, anyway?

Comment: What does the generated html look like? You probably can target that with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Put style / styleClass tag in the `p:column` of `<p:columnGroup type="header">`

Tested using Primefaces 5.3, Mojarra 2.2

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.persons}" var="person">
<p:subTable value="#{person.children}" var="child">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Person: #{person.name}" />
    </f:facet>
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="Name" style="width: 500px"/>
            <p:column headerText="Years" />
            <p:column headerText="Birth Date" />                
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{child.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{child.years}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{child.birthDate}" />
    </p:column>
</p:subTable
</p:dataTable
```